# Selenium find_element CSS, how to?

Tags: python, css, selenium

I am trying to test logging in to twitter and this is a element section of the login box however I tried xpath with  but it doesn't work.

CSS element

```
<input autocapitalize="sentences" autocomplete="username" autocorrect="on" name="text" spellcheck="true" type="text" dir="auto" class="r-30o5oe r-1niwhzg r-17gur6a r-1yadl64 r-deolkf r-homxoj r-poiln3 r-7cikom r-1ny4l3l r-t60dpp r-1dz5y72 r-fdjqy7 r-13qz1uu" value="">
```

```
t = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[5]/label/div/div[2]/div/input')
```

error selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

How can this be done using CSS_SELECTOR?

Answer (score 0):

According to provided `HTML` you can use below ways

```
username_input = self.browser.find_element(By.NAME, "text")
username_input.send_keys('send username here')
```

A way better approach will be to induce `ExplicitWait`.

**Code**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 30)

username_input = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "text")))
username_input.send_keys('send username here')
```

**Imports**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

***CSS selector will be:***

```
input[name='text']
```

***XPATH will be:***

```
//input[@name='text']
```

Hope this solve your issue.